# Why is not my handler executing?

Tags: java, android

I have the following code:

```
   int x=0; 
    private void startTimerThread() {
        System.out.println("enter");
        System.out.println("percentage"+percentage); 
        System.out.println("x"+x); 

        final Handler handler = new Handler();
        Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                for (x = 0; x>= percentage; x++ ) {  
                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(1000);
                    }    
                    catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    handler.post(new Runnable(){
                        public void run() {
                            textpercentage.animate(x, x++);
                            System.out.println("enter"+x);
                    }
                });
                }
            }
        };
        new Thread(runnable).start();
    }
```

I am trying to animate digits on a textview using timely text view, however when I call startTimerThread from my code which is outside of onCreate neither do I get the text view to display not does the system.out execute. What do I miss here?

Comment: can you show us the value of x and percentage?

Comment: Oh Darn how could I miss that, off to debug!

Comment: no need for any Thread: just use a `Handler` and `postDelayed()`  method (or `send[Empty]MessageDelayed()`)

Comment: What is percentage in this code ? First tell this, so, we can help you

Comment: in Chronological order:

`12-26 17:36:49.643: I/System.out(6840): enter
12-26 17:36:49.643: I/System.out(6840): percentage100
12-26 17:36:49.643: I/System.out(6840): x0`

Comment: you have `x>= percentage` in the for loop which is wrong, but again: you **don't need any Thread** for that

Comment: Yes I want to animate the textview while x > = percentage, can you hint more on what is worng there?

Comment: you mean while "x < percentage", right?

Comment: Darn again! You are right!

Comment: Your pointer fixed it, you can post an answer and I will accept.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try like this

```
Handler handler = new Handler();
    int delay=1000;
    Runnable rann=new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            //Write Your logic here which you want to perform periodically
            System.out.println("Handler is running : ");
            //to call the same thread repeatedly calling handler again
            handler.postDelayed(rann, delay);
        }
    };


    private void startHandler() {
        //here the handler will executes the rannable after that particulary delay milli seconds
        handler.postDelayed(rann, delay);
    }

    private void stopHandler() {
        handler.removeCallbacks(rann);
    }
```

Comment: @user2822178 commnts added try once

Comment: Bro it was a problem with the >< signs, I had deviated. Its fixed now :)